# Rails ActionMailer attachment leave blank body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html-email, actionmailer, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an inline attachment (an image) with my ActionMailer-generated email. However, every time I add an attachment, I keep getting a blank email body. I tried generating a bare-bones test email to eliminate other variables in play, but I keep getting the same issue.

I'm using Rails 3.2.13, and the following is my code and failing specs:

**app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb**

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "support@example.com"

  def test
    attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.read Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/emails/logo.png').to_s
    mail(to: 'my_email@gmail.com', subject: 'Testing, Testing')
  end

  def test_no_attachment
    mail(to: 'my_email@gmail.com', subject: 'Testing, Testing')
  end
```

**app/views/contact_mailer/test.html.erb**

```
<p>This is a test.</p>
<p>This is only a test.</p>
<%= image_tag attachments['mhbo_logo.png'].url %>
```

**app/views/contact_mailer/test_no_attachment.html.erb**

```
<p>This is a test.</p>
<p>This is only a test.</p>
```

**spec/mailers/contact_mailer_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ContactMailer do
  describe 'test' do
    it 'should send' do
      ContactMailer.test.deliver
      ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count.should eq 1
      ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.body.should match /This is a test./
    end
  end

  describe 'test_no_attachment' do
    it 'should send' do
      ContactMailer.test_no_attachment.deliver
      ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count.should eq 1
      ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.body.should match /This is a test./
    end
  end
end
```

The second test passes but the first test fails with the following:

```
 Failure/Error: ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.body.should match /This is a test./
   expected  to match /This is a test./
 # ./spec/mailers/contact_mailer_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Thus, the body of this email is blank.

What could be wrong with my code? or is something wrong with the way I'm testing this? I've tested many other emails with the same syntax, though granted none with attachments. I'm also confused because I thought adding attachments would send multi-part emails, so that `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count` would be greater than 1. Am I mistaken in that?

I'm a bit lost here, so any and all help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that I was testing the email content incorrectly. Multipart emails, such as those with attachments, send as a single email but with multiple parts, which are accessed like so:

```
ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.body.parts
```

So, in order to find the part corresponding to the HTML body, I wrote this test:

```
ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.body.parts.detect{|p| p.content_type.match(/text\/html/)}.body.should match /This is a test./
```

I refactored this code into a macro to make my tests more readable:

**spec/macros/testing_macros.rb**

```
module TestingMacros
  def last_email_html_body
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.body.parts.detect{|p| p.content_type.match(/text\/html/)}.body
  end
end
```

**spec/mailers/contact_mailer_spec.rb**

```
…
last_email_html_body.should match /This is a test./
…
```

Comment: Upvoted because this led me to understand that if there is an attachment, I needed to deal with the email.body.parts instead of just rendering the email.body directly as an HTML blob. Thanks for leading me there.